# Template accessor can not convert from T to T& (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have a templated class:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(T mem)
    {
        member = mem;
    }
    T& GetMember() const
    {
        return(member);
    }

    T member;
};
```

and then I do this:

```
MyClass<bool> test(true);
bool someBool = test.GetMember();
```

And I get a compile error saying it can't convert 'bool' to 'bool&'
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have a const member function, but you are returning a mutable reference from it. (btw cl's error message is `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const bool' to 'bool &'` which makes that clear). That is probably is not your real intent, so either use

```
T GetMember() const
{
  return member;
}
```

or

```
const T& GetMember() const
{
  return member;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T& GetMember() const
```

should be

```
const T& GetMember() const
```

`const` is not just a keyword to make your code look safer, it acutally enforces your code to be safer ;)

Comment: Alternatively, he could qualify `member` as `mutable`, depending upon the desired behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you very much, never saw this keyword. Always great to learn something new.